# Visual Studio Two Tiers Database (DAL)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

Login.aspx

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String tbNRIC = txtLogUsername.Text.ToString();
        String tbPassword = txtLogPassword.Text.ToString();

        PatientDAO fmTd = new PatientDAO();
        fmTd.getPatientByNricPassword(tbNRIC, tbPassword);

        if(?? > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

How to i response.redirect after checking if username and password match?

PatientDAO.cs

```
public int getPatientByNricPassword(String tbNRIC, String tbPassword)
        {
            string DBConnect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString;

            SqlDataAdapter da;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            Patient mypatient = new Patient();

            StringBuilder sqlStr = new StringBuilder();

            int result = 0;

            sqlStr.AppendLine("Select * from Login where");
            sqlStr.AppendLine("tbNRIC = @paratbNRIC AND tbPassword = @paratbPassword");

            try
            {
                SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(DBConnect);
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr.ToString(), myConn);

                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paratbNRIC", tbNRIC);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paratbPassword", tbPassword);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                logManager log = new logManager();
                log.addLog("PatientDAO.getPatientByNricPassword", sqlStr.ToString(), ex);
                mypatient = null;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

How do i pass the result to Login.aspx?

Patient.cs

```
public class Patient
    {
        public string tbNRIC { get; set; }
        public string tbPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

How to check from PatientDAO to see if Username and Password Match and Login.aspx Response.Redirect.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the code I can see.

First in method `getPatientByNricPassword` it seems you are returning `result` variable, but this has not been assigned. Probably you want to return the count of records in that case.

Second, you have not initialized `PatientDAO fmTd = new PatientDAO();` with the credential details.
Initialize the values appropriately -

```
PatientDAO fmTd = new PatientDAO();
fmTd.tbNRIC = tbNRIC; // which is txtLogUsername.Text
fmTd.tbPassword = tbPassword ; //which is txtLogPassword.Text
```

Note that you do not need to put `ToString()` as text property is already string.

Third, you should have variable for example `recordCount` to store result of dal method, which you can further check in `if` condition like this -

```
var recordCount = fmTd.getPatientByNricPassword(tbNRIC, tbPassword);
if(recordCount  > 0)
  {
     Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
  }
```